# get all listbox value by separation of any special character except "," by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I'm getting all listbox value by jquery function. The values are coming in a map separated by comma(","). But I want those values separated by any special char like "~".
   This is my jquery function.

```
var selectedLstUsersCC = $.map( $('#lst_UsersCC option'),
            function(e) { return $(e).val(); } );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to replace the commas with your special character like so:

```
  var userList = selectedLstUsersCC.replace(",","~");
```

Assuming that ´selectedLstUsersCC´ contains the list separated by commas.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It is working. But I have found another way to solve it.

       

       var selectedLstUsersCC = $('#lst_UsersCCExt option').map(function () {
           return this.value;
       }).get().join('~');

Comment: Glad to help. Good alternative. If my answer was helpful please would you approve it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Alex, your suggestion is working fine.
I have found another way which can be done by one step.

```
   var selectedLstUsersCC = $('#lst_UsersCCExt option').map(function () {
                return this.value;
            }).get().join('~');
```